# Convert timestamp to age in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `age` > '19' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10


| id | name | age       |
-------------------------
| 1  | a    | 842479200 |
-------------------------
| 2  | b    | 748562400 |
-------------------------
```

`age` row includes timestamps.
how to convert it to age like 15, 14 , 20 , 25?

Comment: code using timestamp: http://pastebin.com/pG9E3anJ

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to the right format using something like:

```
SELECT people, name, strftime("%Y-%d-%m", age, 'unixepoch') AS age 
FROM `people` WHERE `age` > '19' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```